# Get all options from Select box (selected and non selected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using this code:

```
$('#select-from').each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});

<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple="" size="15">
  <option value="1">Porta iPhone Auto</option>
  <option value="2">Leather Moto Vest</option
</select>
```

I get all the values from that select box that are selected, how do I get also the ones not selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
 $('#select-from option').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn8uH/)

Answer (score 7):

Try below

get all values

```
var valuesArray = $("#select-from option").map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

get selected and unselected values in different array.

```
var values = {
  selected: [],
  unselected:[]
};

$("#select-from option").each(function(){
  values[this.selected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'].push(this.value);
});
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

`this.text` will give the text

`this.value`  will give the value

Answer (score 0):

My version :)

```
$("#select-from option:selected").each(function (i, x) {
    alert($(x).val() + " selected");
});

$("#select-from option:not(:selected)").each(function (i, x) {
    alert($(x).val() + " not selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select-from option').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

This will return all values.

If you want to highlight the selected you could do an `if statement` to check if selected and then merge somthing to the output text with a `+`.

Comment: Seems the OP wants the value, not the text.