# Get the value from all options (selected and not selected) in select multiple form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need some help with my Select multiple form.

When clicking the submit button I want to submit all the values of the options. Selected and not selected options.

So if you take the code below as an example. I would like to get all the option values into an array without needing to select them in the Input.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="cars" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Result:

```
array( [0] => 'volvo', [1] => 'saab', [2] => 'opel', [3] => 'audi' );
```

This post does everything I want but it is done in Javascript: [Get all options from Select box (selected and non selected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731924/get-all-options-from-select-box-selected-and-non-selected). So if this can be done by using Javascript and PHP that would be great, but I have yet not found a solution for that.

Thanks for your help in Advance!

Sincerly, Ledung.

Comment: May I ask why you need the unselected items?

Comment: I want to have two seperate select multiple inputs which I can add and remove Users from. See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0zqbpta/. So I would like to submit the form to the right.

Comment: This obviously can’t be done in PHP, because the values of non-checked options are not submitted to the server in the first place. (At most you could compare a list of all options that you already have available in your PHP code, with what was actually send. But that would be a rather different question.)

Comment: Oh, Thanks alot CBroe for the info! Will think about this the next time I stumble upon a similar front end issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create, with javascript, an additional text input to store all option values:

```js
var my_values = [];
var $select = $('select[name=the_select]');
$select.find('option').each(function() {
  my_values.push($(this).val());
});
$new_input = $('<input type="text" name="all_options">'); // use 'type="hidden"' in production
$new_input.val(my_values.join(','));
$select.parent().append($new_input);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="the_select">
  <option value="val0">value 0</option>
  <option value="val1">value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">value 2</option>
</select>
```

The form will send the additional parameter named "all_options".

This PHP code will create the array:

`$all_options = explode(",", $_GET['all_options']);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly, it wasnt done with PHP but it still works!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `hidden` input into your form which will contain all available options:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="cars" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="allCars">
    <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

and now you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
     // All available options from cars select.
    const options = document.getElementsByName('cars')[0].options;
    // Array with all available cars.
    const allCars = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      allCars.push(options[i].value);
    }
    // Assign cars to hidden input.
    document.getElementsByName('allCars')[0].value = allCars;
  });
</script>
```

In case this is not final answer - hope you'll get the main idea of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

$.map is probably the most efficient way to do this using jquery.

```js
var options = $('#selectData option');
var values = $.map(options ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
console.log(values) //=> all values
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectData" id="selectData">
  <option value="val0">value 0</option>
  <option value="val1">value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this way?

You can structure you data this way.

But when submit, you should use ajax post or create a new form instead of using the old one form submit.

```js
$('#form').submit(function(event){
  var arr=[];
  $('option').each(function(){
    arr.push({
      selected: $(this).is(':selected'),
      value: $(this).val()
    })
  })
  console.log(arr);
  // do ajax form post and redirect
  // or build a new form with data strcture above
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="cars" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```